# Javascript: How to reference a child window that is opened by posting

Tags: javascript, browser, window

I want to reference the child window that I have opened so that I can call some method on it from the parent. To do that I need to keep a reference to the window. All the examples I have found keep the reference by:

```
var windowRef = window.open(...);
```

But I don't use window.open. I submit the form because I need to post data to it:

```
var frmMain = document.forms['frmMain'];
frmMain.action = "http://www.somedomain.com";
link.attr("href");
frmMain.target = "_blank";
frmMain.submit();
```

How can I reference the open window using a post? Thanks!

Comment: You must have opened the window somehow. Submitting your form alone wouldn't do it. What other code do you use?

Comment: No, that code posted above does open the window. The "submit" method does this.

Answer (score 1):

The `open` method of the window object can actually create the reference for you as long as your `target` attribute is set to a real name.

```
var frmMain = document.forms['frmMain'];
frmMain.action = "http://www.somedomain.com";
link.attr("href");
frmMain.target = "myawsmwindow";
frmMain.submit();

var myawsmwindow = window.open("", "myawsmwindow"); // gets you a variable ref to the named window.
```

edit: Here is a demonstration [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/REecq/1/).

Comment: This results in two windows open. "Submit" will open one window while window.open will open a second one. It doesn't matter that you are using the same name for the window. Submit and open are two separate commands. And yes, I tried this. Your example will open a blank window.

Comment: @kojiro: are you sure that all existing browsers exhibit this behaviour? I recall that IE's behaviour differs here, but I am unable to test at the moment.  However, if the `submit()` and `window.open()` lines switch places, I'd expect it to be more consistent.

Comment: @AndyE The jsfiddle above is tested in IE6 and 9. Browser bugs aside, it shouldn't matter what order the code occurs in as far as grabbing the reference goes. The window.open may open the window *before* the form submit happens, but as long as the form submit happens and targets that same window, it doesn't matter. You probably don't want to open a new window in the submit event handler and then return `false`, but my PoC still stands.